# Math not working as expected

Tags: autohotkey

I can't figure out how to use a variable as a math expression. The following code won't return the expected solution but doesnt throw any errors, instead it will just output the contents of the Q variable again in A.

```
Q = 7+5=
StringReplace, Q, Q, =,, 1
A := Q
```

Using `%Q%` or `Q = %Q%` doesn't work. And running `MsgBox, %A%` after it will just return "7+5".
Please help as I'm pretty new to AutoHotKey :)

Comment: 1 line: Don't add equals after 5

Comment: The '7+5=' code is just an example, it is output from an OCR program not set by me so I do not have control over it. Also, the = is being stripped in the second line, so I don't think it is the problem.

Comment: true just a guess I don't really know much about AutoHotKey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out:

http://www.autohotkey.com/community/viewtopic.php?t=17058

This should do it though:

```
Q = 7+5=
StringReplace, Q, Q, =,, 1
StringReplace, Q, Q, +,%A_SPACE%, 1

stringleft, first, Q, 1
stringright, last, Q, 1

x := first + last

MsgBox, %first%, %last%, %x%
```

Comment: I modified this to loop through a string using SubStr and seperate them but thanks for the idea of seperating em.